# When trying to use mouse / import, I'm getting a recursion error / package operation fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit

I'm running a python repl.it environment / project, my code is as stated below:

```
from webbot import Browser
import time
from keyboard import press
import mouse


web = Browser()

tab = 1
add = 1

web.go_to('https://tankster.io')
time.sleep(7.5)

mouse.move(585, 335, absolute=True, duration=0.5)
mouse.click('left')

text_areas = web.find_elements(xpath='//input')
web.type(web.Key.ENTER,into=text_areas[0].text)

time.sleep(3)

global h
h = 100

while(h > 99):
  press('enter')
  time.sleep(5)
```

Start-up starts out normal:

Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry add mouse

Using version ^0.7.1 for mouse

Then produces the following error:

```
[RecursionError]
maximum recursion depth exceeded
exit status 1


Repl.it: Package operation failed.
```

I've never gotten any errors like this before, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mouse` module requires [root access in linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-login-as-super-user/), [which is not available to the `runner` (i.e., the repl.it user)](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-to-Give-Root-Privileges-to-install-pkg/47247). See "known limitations" at the end of [the `mouse` PyPI description](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) or [the `mouse` repo](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#known-limitations):

> - To avoid depending on X the Linux parts reads raw device files (`/dev/input/input*`) but this requries root.

To automate web UI interaction, I recommend [trying Selenium web drivers](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Can-I-use-selenium/11566) with python instead of `webbot` and `mouse` modules. [Here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) are documentations about how to use.

Comment: Selenium is hard to configure in repl.it... I've succeeded once (a really long time ago) but it no longer works. Any suggestions on that front?